# Where in Source Code Does Laravel 5.2 Convert Route Prefixes to Parameters

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5, routes, phpunit, mockery

In a nutshell, I keep finding forums on how to use the route prefixes, but I am wondering where it is in the source code that Laravel converts route prefixes into parameters that can be used in the views example: {customer_id}

It looks like on 794 of Illuminate/Routing/Route.php getPrefix() is used to get the prefix of the route instance; however, I'm not seeing where that is actually called.

I am trying to test a controller in Laravel 5.2 with PHPUnit/Mockery, Doctrine 2, and about 15 other dependencies.  I have route prefixes of admin and customer that need to be pulled down as parameters.  Everything on the live site works fine, so I know the actual code is correct.  The other parameters work fine -- just not static prefixes.  The tests worked great with Eloquent and had no problems converting the prefixes to parameters before my manager added a bunch of new dependencies.  Now the prefix parameter returns null during testing on every test.  One of the new dependencies broke something involved with testing--likely autoloading.

I could be looking in the wrong direction seeing how we are using so many dependencies that makes it extremely difficult to track down problems, but I've already found that Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
was autoloaded prior to the merge, and now it needs to be manually added to the testcase.  I'm wondering if this isn't the same thing I need to do to get the route prefixes to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was looking in the wrong place and converting the first static prefix to a variable was a new custom feature that parsed the route in helpers.php added by a coworker.  That method was then called from middleware--which I had middleware turned off for testing, so the test never retrieved that first parameter.